# Fast Redirect Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When the user enters my page `example.com` I detect if they have an active session. If so, I redirect it to `example.com/dashboard`. My code:

```
 <head>
    . . . .
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-app.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/config.js"></script>
  
    <script>
         firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( function( user ){
             if( user ){ window.location = 'dashboard'; }
         });
    </script>
 </head>
```

It works fine, but it is very slow. First the page is loaded and then it does the redirection. I want this to happen immediately

expected result (miro.com): https://streamable.com/y6z7mc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `onAuthStateChanged` callback does not trigger immediately, and there's nothing you can do to speed that up.  It simply takes time for the auth SDK to initialize, try to load the user's token, and verify it.  You can read more about how this works in [this blog post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0).

You can instead show some sort of loading indicator or wait screen while the user waits for this process to complete.